# is there an easy way to read a file on Cypress and make an array out of it

Tags: javascript, file

I have tried using readFile, readFileSync, and I get errors like readFileSync is not a function.

I have fs imported but not sure what I am missing.

Cypress is using Javascript and i dont see why it wont work.

Reading a file which looks like this and saving contents as an array

banana
apples
oranges

['bananas', 'apples', 'oranges']

I have tried using readFile, readFileSync, and I get errors like readFileSync is not a function.

I have fs imported but not sure what I am missing.

Cypress is using Javascript and i dont see why it wont work.

Reading a file which looks like this and saving contents as an array

banana
apples
oranges

['bananas', 'apples', 'oranges']

Comment: Have you tried importing valid JSON and then parsing the content through `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Could you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If these values ​​are not automatically generated, you can easily read them through the Cypress fixture

There 1. You can store those values in a JSON file

[image]

2. then easily you can read them,

```
describe('Read Array via Fixture', () => {
    
    it('Test', () => {
        cy.fixture('example.json').then((array) => {
            for (let index in array) {
                cy.log(index + " : " + array[index])
              }
        });
    
    });
});
```

output
[image]

In your second question, saving contents as an array

here I am not sure how you trying to read the contents,
so you can refer this, https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8034

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't use fs directly in cypress (there are tasks to use node btw) but there are `cy.readFile()` that you can use to read a file or `cy.writeFile()` to write a file.

However in your specific case since you are reading an object not plain text then I recommend using @niluka's solution.

[cy.readFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile)

[cy.writeFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile)